# Get data from 3 dropdown menus and populate a 4 one from db based on that 3 parameters

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, joomla

I need to know what is wrong. The PHP doesn't return anything. I think the variables don't get on the PHP file. Please help me to find out what goes wrong.

```
<?php
defined('_JEXEC') or die;
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$an=$_POST['an'];
$fac=$_POST['fac'];
$uni=$_POST['uni']; 

$result1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM drv_uni_$uni WHERE an='$an'");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result1)){
     $display_string = "<option value=\"".$row['materie']."\">". $row['materie'] ."</option>";
}
     echo $display_string;
?>
```

Javascript

```
function  getValFromDb() {
    var valoare_selectata_uni = document.getElementById('category').value;
    var valoare_selectata_fac = document.getElementById('subcategory').value;
    var valoare_selectata_an = document.getElementById('an').value;
    var url = "modules/mod_data/tmpl/script.php";
    var params = 'uni=' + valoare_selectata_uni + 
                 '&fac=' + valoare_selectata_fac +
                 '&an=' + valoare_selectata_an;

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { 
        AJAX=new XMLHttpRequest(); 
    } else { 
        AJAX=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); 
    }

    if (AJAX) {
        AJAX.open("POST", url, false);
        AJAX.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        AJAX.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if(AJAX.readyState == 4 && AJAX.status == 200) {
                var answer = AJAX.responseText;
                document.getElementById('materie').innerHTML = answer;
            }
        }; 
        AJAX.send(params);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is this: `drv_uni_$uni`

Comment: @Edga, if `$uni=1` then it'll write `drv_uni_1` in the sql.

Comment: Can you show us your table schema, or/and any error you're seeing ?

Comment: try browsing that file with a querystring containing that variables. if there's something on the screen, then the error is on javascript side.

Comment: problem is not about database because this script if had static variables and included on the main it shows good. the problem is that the php file doesn.t get the variables and the JS doesn.t receive back from php. i said this because nothing is shown back not even an error.. how can i see if data is returning in JS? I DONT KNOW IF THIS FILES ARE GOOD BUT.. i want to get that 3 variables from 3 drodpwons. (this is corect done the variables are populated ok) and with this 3 collected inJS i made a query in db to show data for the 4th dropdown menu. hope it is clear

Answer (score 0):

You can debug the code using below few methods.

1. You can 1st `print_r($result1)` and see whether your SQL returns the results you want. If not try working on the query.
2. `$display_string = "<option value=\"".$row['materie']."\">". $row['materie'] ."</option>";` is wrong you should have a it like below. `$display_string .= "<option value=\"".$row['materie']."\">". $row['materie'] ."</option>";`. You are missing `.=`
3. `if had static variables and included on the main it shows good.` Rather than using `$_POST` use Joomla's way of retrieving POST data `JRequest::getVar('an');`. **[Read more](http://docs.joomla.org/Retrieving_and_Filtering_GET_and_POST_requests_with_JRequest%3a%3agetVar)**

let me know the results I might be able to help you.

Comment: i made the changes .with print function insertet nothing showed up with static or with dinamic values... so i guess when i select the last parameter from last dropwon menu nothing happens . i attach a photo with firebug an hope you.ll see better what is happening. in response tab of firebug is nothing... if you know any alternative method to do this i am glad to listen.  http://i50.tinypic.com/2qbeniv.jpg